# phonegap and used .html, .css, .javascript. (how my app works)

Tags: eclipse, cordova

i am new developer here, write now i am develop application 
using blackberry web/widget (eclipse) and the language i used is phonegap where phonegap support .html, .css,  .javascript. so i want to know how my application work? is it 
depend on os version or phone model or both?

thanks.

regards,
jamaley.

Comment: What do you mean with how your application works?

Comment: what i mean here my app work depend on OS version or phone model or both? where i develop app using BB web/widget(eclipse) and language used is Phonegap. thanks for your respond.

Comment: PhoneGap is a framework, not a language. If you are asked to clarify a question you should update/edit the original question, not add further comments. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You develop with phonegap.
This is a framework that let's you create mobile apps with access to phonefunctions by using web standards.

You will need to compile your app for each platform (OS). Seperatly.
Of course you will need to take in mind the different resolutions for each phone.